# Aligning two 3D objects in cartesian coordinates

Tags: python

I have two copies of the same molecule as .xyz file. This means that each atom is has X, Y and Z coordinates. However, you can rotate the molecule and obtain different coordinates for each atom, although the relative positions are the same and the molecule remains the same. I want to align the two molecules using three atoms as reference points. However, I am struggling to completely align the two molecules.

Firstly, I align both molecules by translation for a single atom. Then, I am doing two subsequent rotation using rotation matrices as explained [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d). For some reason, I need to take the negative of the cross product of both vectors and use a sinus instead of a cosinus to get both structures to be perfectly aligned (I discovered this after a lot of trial and error).

For the second rotation, I project both vectors I want to align on a plane defined by the rotation vector. This is necessary because I don't want to rotate along the cross product of the two vectors to align, since that would disalign the rest of the molecule. Instead, I rotate along the two already aligned vectors. The project allows me to find the angle in the plane between the two vectors, and thus the rotation necessary.

However, this code does not properly align the two molecules.

"group1[0]" contains the XYZ coordinates of the three atoms to align in a list. Likewise for "group2[0]" and the structure 2.

```
#Point 1: align the functional groups to the origin

O1 = np.array(coords1[group1[0][0]])
O2 = np.array(coords2[group2[0][0]])

mat_2 = np.zeros((len(atoms2), 3))

for ind, c in enumerate(coords1):
    coords1[ind] = np.array(c) - O1

for ind, c in enumerate(coords2):
    coords2[ind] = np.array(c) - O2
    mat_2[ind] = coords2[ind]

#Point 2: align according to a first vector
v1 = np.array(coords1[group1[0][1]])#Since atom 1 is the origin, the coordinates is the vector already
v2 = np.array(coords2[group2[0][1]])#Since atom 1 is the origin, the coordinates is the vector already

v1 = v1/np.linalg.norm(v1)
v2 = v2/np.linalg.norm(v2)

#Let v be the axis of rotation
v = -np.cross(v1, v2)#why do I need a minus here?

if np.linalg.norm(v) != 0:
    a = np.arccos(np.dot(v1, v2)/(np.linalg.norm(v1)*np.linalg.norm(v2)))
    #c = np.dot(v1, v2)*np.cos(a)

    c = np.dot(v1, v2)*np.sin(a)#The internet says cos, but this works perfectly

    vx = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0], 0]])

    rot_mat = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) + vx + vx.dot(vx)*(1-c)/(1-c**2)
    mat_2 = np.array(mat_2)

    R_mat_rot = np.matmul(rot_mat, mat_2.T).T
else:
    exit(0) 

coords3 = R_mat_rot.copy()

#I get exactly what I want up until here

#Point 3: Rotate along atom2-atom1 (v1) to align the third atom
v = -v1.copy()

v2 = np.array(coords3[group2[0][2]]) - np.array(coords3[group2[0][0]]) #Since atom 1 is the origin, the coordinates is the vector already
v2 = v2/np.linalg.norm(v2)

v1 = np.array(coords1[group1[0][2]]) - np.array(coords1[group1[0][0]]) #Since atom 1 is the origin, the coordinates is the vector already
v1 = v1/np.linalg.norm(v1)

if np.linalg.norm(v) != 0:
    #consider v to be the vector normal to a plane
    #we want the projection of v1 and v2 unto that plane
    vp1 = np.cross(v, np.cross(v1, v)) - np.array(coords1[group1[0][0]])
    vp1 = vp1/np.linalg.norm(vp1)

    vp2 = np.cross(v, np.cross(v2, v)) - np.array(coords3[group2[0][0]])
    vp2 = vp2/np.linalg.norm(vp2)

    #we find the angle between those vectors on the plane
    a = np.arccos(np.dot(vp1, vp2))/(np.linalg.norm(vp1)*np.linalg.norm(vp2))

    #rotation of that amount
    c = np.dot(v1, v2)*np.cos(a)
    vx = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0], 0]])

    rot_mat = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) + vx + np.dot(vx, vx)*(1-c)/(1-c**2)

    R_mat_rot = np.matmul(rot_mat, coords3.T).T

coords4 = R_mat_rot.copy()#Final coordinates
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this code does not properly align the two molecules."? In which way is the alignment bad? Is the algorithm working if the three reference points are only translated/rotated in one plane with respect to each other?

Comment: The two molecules are still aligned along the first vector, but there is still an angle between the two ([image](https://i.ibb.co/3T9Bs5b/Align.png); the two red oxygens should be superposed, for example). It seems like the rotation angle is wrong, but I really can't find how to fix it properly.